# Puxar diversas imagens do mesmo id no bd

Tags: php

Estou com uma baita dificuldade ao puxar para o front-end 4 imagens do mesmo id que tenho no banco de dados.

Consegui inserir normalmente as imagens no banco de dados, estou usando duas tabelas distintas.

Segue o banco de dados abaixo a primeira:

```
Tabela: produtos
id  nome       descricao             slug
1  produto um  descricao do produto  produto-um
```

Segue abaixo a segunda:

```
tabela:produto_imagens
id  produto_id  imagens
1      1        hsaudhuahdsu.jpg
2      1        gsagaasftfsa.jpg
3      1        assdoakdaado.jpg
```

segue o código php abaixo:

```
<?php
$url = explode('/',$_GET['url']);
$produto = MySql::run()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `produto` WHERE slug = ?");
$produto->execute(array($url[0]));// código para ver se a url existe.
if($profile->rowCount() == 0){
die("a página não existe!");

}
foreach ($produto as $key => $value) {
$produto->fetchAll();
$imagens = MySql::run()->prepare("SELECT * FROM 
`produto_imagens` WHERE produto_id = $value[id]");
$imagens->execute();

?>
// nao coloquei as tags do php pq se nao o 
//codigo nao aparece para vcs.

<h2>Nome do produto:  echo $value['nome'];<h2>
<h3>Descrição do produto</h3>
<p>echo $value['descricao']; </p>
<?php }?>//fecha foreach"produto".

<?php
foreach ($imagens as $key => $value) {
$imagens = $imagens->fetch()['imagem'];

?>
<img src='echo $imagens'>   
<?php } ?>//fecha foreach $imagens.
```

Assim, consigo recuperar todos od dados da tabela "produtos", e da tabela "produto_imagens" consigo recuperar somente a primeira, e se replico o código  ele retorna a mesma imagem.
Alguém sabe como que puxo do banco de dados todas as imagens do mesmo id da tabela produtos e mostro para o usuário no front-end?

Comment: Não seria interessante salvar apenas o caminho das imagens no banco e as imagens no disco? Grandes aplicações fazer assim pra facilitar a manutenção e reduzir o tamanho do banco, dando mais rapidez

Answer (score 2):

Você esta **sobrescrevendo** a variável imagens.

```
foreach ($imagens as $key => $value) {
    $imagens = $imagens->fetch()['imagem']; // <====== AQUI
                                            // Já existe a variável $imagens
```

Por isso esta mostrando apenas 1 imagem, pois você está sempre sobrescrevendo ela com o nome de uma imagem, dentro do foreach.

Você esta **sobrescrevendo** a variável imagens.

*Outra coisa que encontrei* no seu código que achei estranho foi essa parte:

```
<img src='echo $imagens'>
```

Você esta executando um `echo` sem as tags do PHP antes.

## Código corrigido

```
foreach ($imagens as $key => $value) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $value ?>">
<?php }
```

Comment: Pior ainda, nem dá pra saber o que está acontecendo pq não tem um código funcional na pergunta (abre { mas não fecha)

Comment: Também, realmente está bem complicado de entender.

Comment: De qq forma, sua observação é válida, por isso upei.

Comment: Então...eu tirei as tags php e as chaves...acabei esquecendo algumas, porque não estava conseguindo postar no forum com as tags... vou tentar editar.

Comment: Patrick Maciel, tirei ['imagem'], ai coloquei assim: <img src="<?php echo $value['imagem']?>" />, e retornou somente uma imagem. e ao invés de fetch()- deu erro com fetch--, coloquei fetchAll()

Comment: @Leandro coloquei a correção na resposta. Teste e me avise por favor.